# Using jQuery Mobile 1.0. not able to scroll to the top of the window in mobile device

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.0 have a listview with say 100 items.

When I scroll all the way to the bottom and navigate back to the previous screen, and come back to a list view now with say 3 or 4 items I get a blank white space in the scroll area.

I think it remembers where my earlier position of the Scroll down was and then it holds on to it. And for a list view with fewer items I am not able to go to the top of the list.

I have tried several things like:

```
$.mobile.silentScroll and $(window).scroll(0,0)
```

and

```
$(document).scrollTop(0,0)
```

but with no success.

Can you please advise?

My content in DOM is a div with `data-content = scroller` --> Div with Form --> List View.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **mobileinit** event, put this code:

```
$('#uptotop').live('click', function() {
               $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1000, function(){
               $('body').clearQueue(); });
});
```

Then you can create a **button** like this:

```
<a id="uptotop" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u">Back to Top!</a>
```

I've tested on IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, ipad's Safari and it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this but it does not seem to work.  I do not see the scrolltop position changing for my list view. Clicking the button("uptotop" has no effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: THe only thing that does work is this but I am not able to trigger this from a buttom click:  $("#AccountOpportunitiesScreenDiv  div[data-role=scroller]").offset({top:20})

$("#AccountOpportunitiesScreenDiv  div[data-role=scroller]").css("top","0")

Comment: you can see the working code of the above script here http://test.slimspa.eu/andrea/mobile/famiglia.php?fam=011
(scroll down and click on any up-arrow to scroll back to top)